# how to add video in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
const sintel = require('./assets/Bleach - Ending 6 _ My Pace.mp4')
class Hero extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <Video source={{ uri: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' }}></Video>
   )
 }
}
const App = () => {
 return (
   <View style={styles.default}>

     <Hero></Hero>
   </View >
 )
}
export default App;
```

this don't working, i try put the local path in variable, and just , it's not working
i try use the other library, but in conclusion i don't have what i want - it's still don't working

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `height` and `width` to your `Video` component like this:

```
class Hero extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Video 
        style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} 
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' }} 
      />
    )
  }
}
```

If there is no content between opening and closing JSX tags or there are no child elements, you can use self closing tag `<Hero />`.

```
const App = () => {
 return (
   <View style={styles.default}>
     <Hero />
   </View>
 )
}
```

Same for `Video` component:

```
<Video 
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }} 
  source={{ uri: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' }} 
/>
```

Comment: thx, but i have an issue null is not  an object (evaluating  'RCTVideoIstance.Constants'

Comment: Are you developing your app with expo? If so you can try using ```expo-av``` package for videos and use it in the similar manner:
```import { Video } from 'expo-av'``` and installation (if you are using npm):
```npm install --save expo-av```

If not using expo, try linking the package using this command: ```react-native link react-native-video ```

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Feel free to use a "tick" option next to my answer so developers who bump into the same issue in the future can easily find an answer to their concern :)

Comment: im so sorry, i can't find the button for 'tick'  :-(

Comment: one more isssue

Comment: local path didn't worknig... <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={require('./assets/Bleach - Ending 6 _ My Pace.mp4')}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        isLooping
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />